# How to get one item from body API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api

I am working on a project that I have to authenticate e get a token from API body content.

How can I Get only the access_token and save it on a variable to use in another API?

I tried too many things to access it. I think it´s something very easy to do, but I don´t know how!

I am new in node/typescript.

Thank you!

Result:

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiIAU6l9z2zMQiI9g",
    "refresh_token": "AFGpstweytwtewetwetwetwetwetwet2Fg",
    "scope": "default",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

```
export const chamada = (event, context, callback) => {

    var request = require('request');
    console.log('fora');
    request.post('http://MY_API',
        { json: { key: 'value' } },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 201) {                
                console.log('dentro');
                console.log(body);
            }
            else {
                console.log(response.statusCode);
            }
        }
    );  

    const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve('success');
    });
    p.then(() =>
        callback(null, {
            message: 'Go Serverless Webpack (Ecma Script) v1.0! First module!',
            event,
        })
    ).catch((e) => callback(e));

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the property from the response. Inside of the first if in the callback, you can just access `body.access_token` and do whatever you like with it.

Not sure I understand what you mean by "use it in another api". Maybe you can add more description on how you want to use it?

By the way, I see that the library that you are using (request) [is marked as deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142), so if possible, you might want to replace it.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel!!
Exactly o what I need!
Sorry for my poor english, it isn´t my first language.
And yes, I need the value from acces_token to put in another variable and use it in anoter request to authenticate.
Thank you again! I am going to see the "Request" and I will try to use another type of request.